# How to convert unsigned char to NSString in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios4

Can anyone tell me how to convert an unsigned char to an NSString?

Here's the code I am using, but for some reason if I try to do anything with the NSString, like set a UITextView text, it gives me an error. The NSLog works correctly though. Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)onTagReceived:(unsigned char *)tag
{

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSString *myTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x\n",tag[0],tag[1],tag[2],tag[3],tag[4]];

NSLog(@"currentTag: %@",myTag);

[displayTxt setText:myTag];

[pool release];

}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If `tag` is a C string (null-terminated, that is), then you can use `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)tag]`. If you want the hex values, then your code using `%02x` is fine.

Answer (score 3):

@jtbandes: you are correct. The other way you can do this:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCString:tag length:strlen(tag)];
```

Comment: This method has been deprecated and should not be used. See the [NSString class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for other options.